# Do I need to add @Inject for predefined binding when I use Hilt in Android Studio?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm reading the article *Using Hilt in your Android app*.

The Code A is from the [section](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#7).

I was told the following content:

*AppNavigatorImpl depends on a FragmentActivity. Because an AppNavigator instance is provided in the Activity container , FragmentActivity is already available as a predefined binding.*

so I think I can replace Code A with  Code B

But I get the error *@Inject fields may not be final* when I compile Code B, why?

**Code A**

```
interface AppNavigator {   
    fun navigateTo(screen: Screens)
}


class AppNavigatorImpl @Inject constructor(private val activity: FragmentActivity) : AppNavigator {
   ...
}


@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject lateinit var navigator: AppNavigator
    ...

}
```

**Code B**

```
// The same

class AppNavigatorImpl @Inject constructor(@Inject private val activity: FragmentActivity) : AppNavigator {
   ...
}


// The same
```

Comment: remove private from injected field

Comment: Thanks! but I get the same error when I remove `private` in Code B.